# Why is $SU(2)$ a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^8$?

Tags: differential-geometry, submanifold

Let $SU(2) := \{A \in M_2(\mathbb{C}): \det A = 1, AA^\dagger = I_2 = A^\dagger A\}$.

Is this an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^8$? I tried the regular value theorem but this seems to be fruitless here. Should I use the definition with charts?

Comment: "seems to be fruitless here" - why exactly? How did you apply the theorem?

Comment: You would need a map $f$ such that $SU(2)$ is the inverse image of a regular value. The determinant map doesn't work.

Comment: Hint: you can take several maps at once. E.g. if your manifold is the intersection of preimages $f^{-1}(a)$ and $g^{-1}(b)$, then take $f\times g : \mathbb R^8 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ defined by $(f\times g)(x) = (f(x), g(x))$ and take the preimage $(f \times g)^{-1}(a, b)$. Does this help?

Comment: I will try. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the defining equations to show that every $M \in \operatorname{SU}(2)$ is of the form $\begin{pmatrix} a & -\bar{b} \\ b & \bar{a} \end{pmatrix}$ for some $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 1$.

This normalization also allows you to set up a nice diffeomorphism between $S^3 \subset \mathbb{R}^4$ and $\operatorname{SU}(2)$.

Comment: I'm actually trying to prove this question to show that the map sending $(a,b)$ to the matrix you wrote down is a diffeomorphism, and I got that it is a bijection and the smoothness will follow once I get that $SU(2)$ is a submanifold (then I can restrict an obvious smooth map to the submanifold). So, I can't use this...

Comment: I think that this normalization lets you write down polynomial equations cutting out $\operatorname{SU}(2)$ from $\mathbb{R}^8$. Let $x_i + i y_i$, $1 \le i \le 4$ give an identification between $\mathbb{R}^8$ and $\operatorname{M}(2, \mathbb{C})$. Then, we have equations $x_1 = x_4, y_1 = -y_4$, and so forth.